# A question about projections of product measure space

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I am considering the space $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ of real-valued sequences with the sigma-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ generated by sets of the form

$$\{\omega \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} : \omega_k \in B\}$$

as $k$ ranges through $\mathbb{N}$ and $B$ through the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\mathcal{F}'$ be the sub-sigma algebra generated by the sets

$$\{\omega \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} : \omega_k \in B\}$$

as $k$ ranges through $k \geq 2$ and $B$ through the Borel sets.

My very simple questions is, how to show that:

$$\{\omega: \omega_1 = 0\} \notin \mathcal{F}' .$$

My problem is that you can't write down a 'typical' element of the RHS explicitly. Is the only way to do this by transfinite induction?

Many thanks for your help.

EDIT: I am aware that it is possible to define a probability measure on the space and derive the contradiction $1/2=1/4$ using independence of $\mathcal{F}'$ and the sigma-algebra generated by the first co-ordinate mapping. However, I don't find this answer satisfying as it creates what seems like extraneous structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define

$$
\Sigma := \{M \subset \Bbb{R}^\Bbb{N} \, \mid \, \forall \omega \in \Bbb{R}^\Bbb{N} \, \forall x \in \Bbb{R} : \omega \in M \Leftrightarrow \omega^x \in M\},  
$$

where $(\omega^x)_1 = x$ and $(\omega^x)_k = \omega_k$ for $k \geq 2$.

Intuitively, $\Sigma$ contains all those subsets of $\Bbb{R}^\Bbb{N}$ which "do not depend on the first component of their elements".

Now

1. show that $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra which contains all your generators.
2. conclude $\mathcal{F}' \subset \Sigma$.
3. show $\{\omega \, \mid \, \omega_1 = 0\} \notin \Sigma$.
4. Finish the proof.

EDIT: This is often a nice way to show that a certain set is not contained in a $\sigma$-algebra: Find a property which all your generators satisfy, which the set in question does not satisfy and finally verify that all sets with your property form a $\sigma$-algebra.